# PDO Page Pagination with DATE variable in SQL

Tags: php, post, pdo, pagination, timepicker

I have a PHP web application prepared with MySQL and I decided to pass PDO I am having trouble with pagination.

This is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" />
            <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/timepicker.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function(){
                $('#time').datetimepicker({
                                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss "
                                    });
                                    minDate: getFormattedDate(new Date())
                                    function getFormattedDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
    return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
            });
        </script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function(){
                $('#time1').datetimepicker({
                                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                                timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss "
                                    });
                                    minDate: getFormattedDate(new Date())
                                    function getFormattedDate(date) {
    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = date.getFullYear().toString().slice(2);
    return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
            });
        </script>
        <body>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                                <input class="input-medium" type="text" name="time" id="time" value="start_date"/>  
                                <input class="input-medium" type="text" name="time1" id="time1" value="end_date"/>  
                                <button style="margin-bottom:10px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Getir</button>
                    </form> 
</body>
</html>
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
error_reporting(0); 
$time = $_POST['time'];
$time1 = $_POST['time1'];
try {
    require_once('conn.php');
    $cepbankSUM = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(tutar) FROM cepbank WHERE tarih BETWEEN :time AND :time1");
    $cepbankSUM->bindParam(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
    $cepbankSUM->bindParam(':time1', $time1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
    $cepbankSUM->execute();
    $row_cepbankSUM = $cepbankSUM->fetch();
    // Find out how many items are in the table
    $cepbank = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cepbank WHERE tarih BETWEEN :time AND :time1');
    $cepbank->bindParam(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
    $cepbank->bindParam(':time1', $time1, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
    $cepbank->execute();
    $total = $cepbank->fetchColumn();
    // How many items to list per page
    $limit = 20;

    // How many pages will there be
    $pages = ceil($total / $limit);

    // What page are we currently on?
    $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
        'options' => array(
            'default'   => 1,
            'min_range' => 1,
        ),
    )));

    // Calculate the offset for the query
    $offset = max($page - 1, 0)  * $limit;

    // Some information to display to the user
    $start = $offset + 1;
    $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

    // The "back" link
    $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="?page=1" title="First page">&laquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';

    // The "forward" link
    $nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';

    // Display the paging information
    echo '<div id="paging"><p>', $prevlink, ' Page ', $page, ' of ', $pages, ' pages, displaying ', $start, '-', $end, ' of ', $total, ' results ', $nextlink, ' </p></div>';

    // Prepare the paged query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM cepbank WHERE tarih BETWEEN :time AND :time1 ORDER BY tarih DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset');
    // Bind the query params
    $stmt->bindParam(':time', $time, PDO:: PARAM_STR, 20);
    $stmt->bindParam(':time1', $time1, PDO:: PARAM_STR, 20);
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO:: PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO:: PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Do we have any results?
    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        // Define how we want to fetch the results
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $iterator = new IteratorIterator($stmt);
        // Display the results
        foreach ($iterator as $row_cepbank) {
            ?>   
            <table
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row_cepbank['username']?></td>
                                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row_cepbank['trans_id']?></td>
                                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row_cepbank['bank']?></td>
                                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row_cepbank['tutar']?></td>
                                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row_cepbank['operator']?></td>
                                    <td class="center"><?php echo $row_cepbank['tarih']?></td>

                                </tr>                            
                              </tbody>
                </table>      
<?php        } 
    } else {
        echo '<p>No results could be displayed.</p>';
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<p>', $e->getMessage(), '</p>';
}
?>
```

This is work on first run with first result set without any problem when i click the next page i get this error

```
« ‹ Page 0 of 0 pages, displaying -19-0 of 0 results › »

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-20' at line 1
```

But when i write time variable manuel like

```
$time = '2013-08-01 00:00:00';
$time1 = '2013-09-01 00:00:00';
```

There is no problem everything works perfect  but when I try to get time by timepicker with POST method like

```
$time = $_POST['time']; 
$time1 = $_POST['time1'];
```

It fails.

Waiting for your great minds.

I have edit my offset variable to

```
$offset = max($page - 1, 0)  * $limit;
```

No the result is

First run it works ok when I clicked to next page link

```
« ‹ Page 0 of 0 pages, displaying 1-0 of 0 results › »

No results could be displayed.
```

Comment: Have you bothered checking if $POST['time'] returns the date/time in the same format as '2013-08-01 00:00:00'?

Comment: Yes im sure both are same im usig ui timepicker my time format is         'dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss "'

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000] 1064 shows error `-20` The only place I can see -20 being generated is.`$offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit` If `$page == 0` `0-1*20 =-20`.

Comment: I'm still can not solve problem any ideas ??